# How to log source name and version on a MLFlow server from Jupyer lab

Tags: jupyter-lab, mlflow

My setup:

1. I have a running remote MLFlow server.
2. I have a git tracked project consisting of a .ipynb notebook.

What am I doing:

1. Firing up a jupyer lab server from inside the git tracked project.
2. Running mlflow runs from the notebook.

   ````
           mlflow.log_params(params)
           mlflow.log_metrics(metrics)
           mlflow.h2o.log_model(m, "model")```
   ````

Now the issue is, as shown below in the image, MLFlow by default cannot track:

- The source name -> defaults to the ipython kernel name.
- The source version.

[tracking server snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGeCJ.png)

1. Is there a way to manually control the source name and the source version? I noticed the older mlflow versions exposed these two parameters as part of mlflow.start_run() method. This is not the case anymore.
2. Is there a specific setup I need to follow to enable source and version tracking from jupyter by default?